# Is it possible to open mutiple Flask service by using subprocess?

Tags: python, flask, subprocess

I want to create another flask service if some condition was met in main flask service.
code below is a example which i try to run but got error instead.

Flask version 2.2.2
Python 3.10

main.py

```
from flask import Flask
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "sss"

count = 0

@app.route('/chekc')
def sddsfdsfd():
    global count
    if count == 0:
        po = subprocess.Popen('python main2.py',shell=True)
        print(po.pid)
        count += 1
    return 'yoohoo'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```

main2.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/view')
def edy():
    return "sss2"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=333,debug=False)
```

While i expect to create new flask service after redirect to '/chekc' in port 333 i got error as shown below.

```
File "testdoubleflask\main2.py", line 13, in <module>
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=333,debug=False)
  File "testdoubleflask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1188, in run
    run_simple(t.cast(str, host), port, self, **options)
  File "testdoubleflask\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 1071, in run_simple
    srv = make_server(
  File "testdoubleflask\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 852, in make_server
    return ThreadedWSGIServer(
  File "testdoubleflask\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 718, in __init__
    self.socket = socket.fromfd(fd, address_family, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\socket.py", line 545, in fromfd
    nfd = dup(fd)
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

What should i do to solve this error?. Thank you.
PS.If i run both script separately it work fine.

Comment: change port to 2k+

Comment: @sahasrara62 Still not working.